# Model comparison via AIC or BIC for different likelihood maximization procedures

Tags: maximum-likelihood, model-selection, model, aic, bic

Maximum likelihood estimation of different models (which all model the same variable and assume the same likelihood function) is done by a different method for each model. Simple numerical maximization of the likelihood is not possible due to the "curse of dimensionality" and consequently methods like

- composite likelihood estimation
- estimating a subset of parameters by a moment estimator (and the rest by ML)
- iteratively estimating subsets of parameters

are employed. **Assuming all estimation procedures yield consistent parameter estimates but some are more efficient than others, is it sensible to compare the models via AIC or BIC?** What if some procedures are inconsistent?

Comment: Are your models actually different? Or are only the estimation procedures different but the model is one and the same?

Comment: Yes. The models have different autoregressive specifications for the scale matrix of Wishart distribution. F. ex. a stationary MGARCH (which lends itself to covariance targeting) or a DCC-GARCH. More complicated models can only exploit that submatrices of a Wishart distributed random matrix are also Wishart distributed, so many low dimensional models are estimated and a parameter estimates is obtained taking the average of its low dimensional estimates (this is actually consistent and called composite likelihood estimation). [link](http://hdl.handle.net/2078.1/122203) is a reference this.

Comment: So what do you mean by "[different models] assume the same likelihood function"?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misleading statement. The models are different specifications for the same parameter of the Wishart distribution (the scale matrix). Hence they all have the same wishart log-likelihood function.

Comment: You probably mean the errors are Wishart-distributed or something like that, not that the likelihood functions are the same. Because the same likelihood functions mean the same models (except probably for some very special cases).